# Jenkins - how to set build version number based on assembly version?

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild, assemblyversionattribute

Many of the questions on StackOverflow or other blogs indicate how to use the Jenkins build number and the change assembly version plugin to set the AssemblyVersion in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

But I'm trying to do the opposite - setting the jenkins build version to the version from AssemblyInfo.cs? Obviously, I would do this AFTER the source code has been pulled down.

Why do I want to do this?
Reason: I'd like to synchronize the following four 'components'

1. My AssemblyInfo.cs, e.g. [assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.10.*")]
   is my "source of truth" for major.minor versioning
2. At time of build, I'd update the version to, e.g. 2.10.73
   where the 73 is from ${BUILDS_ALL_TIME}
3. We publish our code to our internal nuget server,
   so I'd like the version of the nuget package to be, e.g. 2.10.73
4. I plan to tag/label our source control with the name of the Jenkins Build
5. So I'd like my jenkins build name to be, e.g.
     MyProject.2.10.73

Can I do this?
Namely, I'd like the major.minor version to be set in my AssemblyInfo.cs which is in source control.

Thanks!

Comment: You set the [Build Name](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) in runtime but not the Build Number and also Build Number should be unique, this is basic unit for Jenkins to store build artifacts. Using Build Name Setter Plugin you can set the custom names to build, lot of ways to form a name from environment variables. You have to find a way to read the assembly version from the file and place that as env variable, from here you can use it to set the build name.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Suresh for pointing me in the right direction.

I ended up 
1) Using the EnvInject Plugin (as a build action)

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

2) Wrote my own PowerShell script to read my AssemblyInfo.cs file and output my environment properties
see this post

https://i-script-stuff.electric-horizons.com/environment-inject-variable-with-powershell-and-jenkins/

3) Used the Build Name Setter Plugin to then change the name after the build

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin